# How do I add more models to oregano?

Tags: installation

I installed oregano for studying electronics circuits. But whenever I press simulate button it says:

> Gnucap 2009.12.07 RCS 26.136 The Gnu Circuit Analysis Package Never
>   trust any version less than 1.0 Copyright 1982-2009, Albert Davis
>   Gnucap comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY This is free software, and
>   you are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of  the GNU General
>   Public License, version 3 or later. See the file "COPYING" for
>   details. Untitled.oregano  /usr/share/oregano/models/7400b.model:No
>   such file or directory
>
> #### Too few or none analysis found

I googled and found [this answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oregano/+question/39085). It says it is not bug, and occurs because these models are not included in upstraem tarball. But I don't know how to install these models.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: **I think you are out of luck.**

---

Long answer: reading [the page you linked](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oregano/+question/39085):

> Any additional model has to be added by the user. Oregano models are
>   in spice format and are therefore widely available, for instance this
>   site gives a list of SPICE models available for free on the web:
>
> http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Circuits/Spice/ModelIndex.html

we have good and bad news. The good news are that Oregano uses standard `PSPICE` files (and `PSPICE` has been the most used electronic circuit simulator in the past decade). The bad news are that it seems every model that one would like to use must be manually added to `/usr/share/oregano/models` folder.

This could even be doable, the problem is that reading at the [model index page](http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Circuits/Spice/ModelIndex.html):

> Note that for some of the models you may have to find the appropriate
>   link on the page given, or extract it from a compressed file, but many
>   of these links will take you straight to the manufacturer's download
>   link.
>
> Also note that some sites require you to register first before
>   downloading models. However, once that is done, the models are free.

seems clear that this task is becoming more and more time consuming at each step that we take (and there are even quite a few broken links!).

I've managed to find other resources, for example [this page](http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Circuits/Spice/SpiceBody.html) and [this one](http://www.ti.com/adc/docs/midlevel.tsp?contentId=31690). The last one seemed to be particularly promising, two big zipfiles directly downloadable [here](http://focus.ti.com/packaged_lits/hspice_files/ti_hspice.zip) and [here](http://focus.ti.com/packaged_lits/pspice_files/ti_pspice_models.zip), for example, plus other resources.

Again, the problem now is that unziping these two zipfiles, we have a huge collection of `PSPICE` models without any linking with `Oregano`'s library names (I was trying to use a `TTL 7400b` component - a standard NAND gate - but I couldn't find the component in these two huge libraries, both searching for `7400` and `NAND`).

I've even tried to google for `oregano library torrent` to see if a kind soul had already uploaded such a collection, but still no luck.

So the final response is: **creating your own library is doable, but very time (and mind) consuming.**

Probably you'd better look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/what-are-the-freeware-spice-simulators-available) and pick another free simulator of your choice.

Good luck!

P.s. if you decide to assemble your own library, it would be nice if you'd share it in some way (e.g. torrent, emule, etc.). Many other people will thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: You're not screwed.

I found the models in another, previous github location. Ah the joy of open source shared software on cloud computers. It's like your high school yearbook photo - it never dies...

It seems that once someone migrated the code from the original to the new master distribution, a number of models went missing from the new oregano distro.  Don't quote me just a guess.
Most are located here:    https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/tree/master/data/models

I couldn't find the LF357.model but I googled one here [LF357.cir](http://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceIV/Vendor%20List/National_Semiconductors/Spice/LF357.cir)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but is too late . I hope this will be helpful for others :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you may need to install your own PSPICE models.
From the error message it looks like you need the model for the part 7400.

Here is [a resource for PSPICE models](http://robustdesignconcepts.com/files/pspice/pmindex.htm), including [a library for 7400](http://robustdesignconcepts.com/files/pspice/libs/7400.lib).

Hopefully, you can extract and use it.